# How to verify the equation $\frac{1}{e^{2\pi x} - 1} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} e^{-2\pi kx}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, divergent-series, exponential-sum

May somebody tell me, why
$$
\frac{1}{e^{2 \pi x} - 1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-2 \pi k x}?
$$
It's obviously not Taylor's and Fourier's series, so how to prove it?

Comment: use a "geometric series". $\frac{1}{1-a}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k$.

Comment: @Simon **If** ....$\;|a|<1\;$ ...

Comment: For what values of $\;x\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio well, mathematically of course, yes. But visit a lecture on theoretical physics and you will see it used without any such considerations xD ...

Comment: @Simon I know, and that is due to the fact  that physicists know bananas of mathematics...But it is *also* true with formal power series. Anyway, by the tagging, it seems to be the OP means a real *function*, and he doesn't mean formal series or stuff.

Comment: @DonAntonio Personally, I like physics quite a lot (and doing it mathematically rigorous sadly doesn't really work). Anyway, this is not the place for such a discussion. I was just being lazy with my initial comment. My bad.

Comment: @DonAntonio. I even don't know what are bananas ! Could you, using simple words, explain to the poor physicist I am, what are these animals ? I thank you in advance. Cheers and thanks for the words. I like that !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Mon ami: Bananas = bananes. ...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio. i asked for simple words !! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Geometric series with common ratio $e^{-2\pi x}$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) for the formula of such a sum.

---

Note that your sum start at $k=1$, so we cannot exactly use the "famous" formula $\frac{1}{1-r}$, but rather $\frac{a}{1-r}$.

Comment: Thanks, it's much easier that I thought :)

Answer (score 0):

If $\;x>0\;$ , then $\;|e^{-2\pi x}|<1\;$ , and then we get:

$$\frac1{e^{2\pi x}-1}=\frac1{e^{2\pi x}}\frac1{1-e^{-2\pi x}}=\frac1{e^{2\pi x}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-2k\pi x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-2\pi x(k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-2k\pi x}$$

Comment: The OP didn't say $x$ is real.  For complex $x$ the condition of convergence is $\text{Re}\;x > 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Indeed so, yet (1) the OP also didn't tag her/his question with "complex numbers" , so by default, and because of the basic nature of the question, I assumed we're talking of real numbers, and (2) for $\;x=a+ib\in\Bbb C\;$ , we have that $\;\left|e^{2\pi x}\right|<1\iff e^{2\pi a}<1\iff a<0\;$ , which is exactly the opposite condition you mention. Let the OP choose whatever (s)he wants.

Comment: And the condition for $|e^{-2\pi x}| < 1$ is the condition I mention.

Comment: @GEdgar I referred to original fraction, but then it is all the same condition.